# Turn point of a non planar tensioned rope

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, string

[image]

> Let a rope be fixed at a point "A". The other end of the rope (point "B") is attached (tangentially) to a horizontal drum which is 2m higher than point "A". The drum stretches the rope.
>
> A vertical pillar is located off the vertical plane defined by points A & B. The rope is redirected by the pillar - i.e. it goes from "A" to the pillar and then turns to point "B".
>
> At which height along the pillar will the tensioned rope turn?

My reflections are that the rope either follows a steady slope, or the height along  the pillar is the projection of the slope defined by points A & B, or that the length of the rope should be minimum. However I cannot find any source regarding this matter, and I cannot reach a proof for my reflections.

Comment: Could you include a quick sketch,  for dumbos like me, with no visual imagination?  Thanks

Comment: Edited my post. I hope the sketch helps a bit. thanks

Comment: Note : All 3 of the options in your final paragraph are just different ways of describing the same idea!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At mechanical equilibrium the potential energy has to be at the minimum, see, e.g., https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_total_potential_energy_principle, and for any reasonable rope material the potential energy of the stretched rope should be a monotonically increasing function of its length. Thus the length of the rope between points A and B is minimized by the proper choice of y. This can be solved formally by finding the minimum of the length of the rope given by

$L(y)=(l_1^2+y^2)^{1/2} + (l_2^2+(H-y)^2)^{1/2}$,

where $l_1$ and $l_2$ are horizontal projections of distance from points A and B to the bending point, and H is the height of point B.

Writing $dL/dy=0$ immediately leads to the relation $\frac{y}{l_1} = \frac{H-y}{l_2}$ which is of course the statement of constant slope. The advantage of solving it formally as a minimization problem is that one can apply this principle to similar but more difficult problems, with multiple drums and pillars that have finite diameters, non-trivial cross-section shapes etc.

Comment: Your formal calculation shows what every schoolboy/girl knows : that the shortest distance between 2 points is a straight line. And you give no explanation for why the distance L needs to be minimised.

Comment: @sammy gerbil Good point. Here you have to make some physical arguments regarding the potential energy of the stretched rope, I have added some words on this to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If the rope can slide freely up or down the pillar, then its slope wrt the ground will be constant - ie the same between A and C as between C and B. This is because if we "unwind" the rope and there is a "kink" in it where the slope changes, then there is a component of tension which pulls the rope straight. If there is nothing to oppose this lateral force (such as friction with the pillar) then the rope will slide up/down until it becomes straight, to minimise tension.

After "unwinding" the rope from the pillar so that it is straight, by similar triangles we have :
height at C / height at B = distance AC / distance AB.

If there is friction between the rope and the pillar it will prevent the rope from becoming "straight." The height of the rope on the pillar is then difficult to predict, and depends where it was placed initially.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! By distance AC and BC you mean the distance measured along the rope, or the horizontal distance as measured parallel to the ground?
Is there any hint on how to prove that? Give a start point, i ll do the math! Thanks again!

Comment: Either distance can be used - along the rope or along the ground.  If the rope has a constant slope wrt the ground you can "unwind" it so that it stretches in a straight line. Then use similar triangles.